# Printing first array data amount of times based on second array data

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

sorry for the poor title structure, couldn't think of how to word it.

Anyway, I'm facing a problem when it comes to arrays and loops in C. I need to have a user input 5 letters and store them in the first array. Then I need them to input 5 numbers between 1 and 10 and store those in a second array. Then I need to print the data of the first array the amount of times based on the corresponding number entered in the second array.

For example, if the first letter entered into the first array was A and the first number entered into the second array was 4, i need to print out AAAA.

I know that I need to use a for loop in there somewhere, I'm sure that would be better than a while loop because I will know all the data being used in the loop.

Here is my code so far, it's not much but I hate to ask a question with not even some code in it.

Cheers!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

char input1[5];
int input2[5], i;

printf("Please enter a letter to be stored in the first array: \n");
scanf(" %c", &input1[0]);
printf("Please enter another letter to be stored in the first array: \n");
scanf(" %c", &input1[1]);
printf("Please enter another letter to be stored in the first array: \n");
scanf(" %c", &input1[2]);
printf("Please enter another letter to be stored in the first array: \n");
scanf(" %c", &input1[3]);
printf("Please enter a final letter to be stored in the first array: \n");
scanf(" %c", &input1[4]);
printf("The first array contains these values: %c, %c, %c, %c and %c. \n", input1[0],    input1[1], input1[2], input1[3], input1[4]);

printf("Please enter five numbers between 1 and 10 to be stored in a second array: \n");
scanf("%d", &input2[0]);
printf("Please enter five numbers between 1 and 10 to be stored in a second array: \n");
scanf("%d", &input2[1]);
printf("Please enter five numbers between 1 and 10 to be stored in a second array: \n");
scanf("%d", &input2[2]);
printf("Please enter five numbers between 1 and 10 to be stored in a second array: \n");
scanf("%d", &input2[3]);
printf("Please enter five numbers between 1 and 10 to be stored in a second array: \n");
scanf("%d", &input2[4]);
printf("The second array contains these values: %d, %d, %d, %d and %d \n", input2[0], input2[1], input2[2], input2[3], input26[4]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  for(j=0;j<input2[i];j++){
    printf("%c",input1[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
for(i=0; i < input1.length; i++) {
   char charValue = input1[i];
   int loopNumber = input2[i];
   for(j=0 ;j < loopNumber; j++) {
      printf("%c" + charValue);
   }
}
```